# State shared in multiprocessing when using singleton classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is a toy example of the problem I am having. I have a Singleton class which is used in a large python script. I want to run this script many times with multiple inputs:
The singleton pattern is not necessary here, but in my more complicated real use there is a reason to use it

```
import time
import multiprocessing


class TestClass(object):
  instance = None

  @classmethod
  def get_instance(cls):
    if cls.instance is None:
      print 'creating instance'
      cls.instance = TestClass()
    return cls.instance

  def __init__(self):
    self.data = []


def worker(num):
  tc = TestClass.get_instance()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  tc.data.append(num)
  return tc.data


def main():
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
  res = pool.map(worker, range(10))

  print res 
  print TestClass.get_instance().data


main()
```

When I run the above code, it seems the state of the `TestClass.instance` is (semi-?)shared. The result is:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], ..., [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

If I change the number of processes to 10 I get:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

This is the result I would like.

(If I print `TestClass.get_instance().data` after calling `pool.map()` Then I get an empty list.)

What is the explanation for this behavior?
Is there a way to stop this state sharing and get the second output, but keep control of the number of processes in the pool?

Edit:
When I choose N instances to run the function with M different arguments.
An instance is created N times. Ideally I want M instances created, one for each argument.

Comment: Why are you using a singleton pattern here with multiprocessing? It seems a bit superfluous since each subprocess gets it's own interpreter state (*albeit forked from the parent*).

Comment: Its just a toy example, the real script has much more going on, and parts of that mean I want to use a singleton for various reasons

Comment: But you do realize that your example use of a singleton is kind of useless right? Since you spawn multiple instances of ``TestClass`` anyway in each process? If you have ``processes=10`` you'll have 10 instances of ``TestClass`` created.

Comment: Yes, thats what I intended but doesnt seem to be happening (see first output). The singletons are required within each process, but I would like separate instances across different processes. I understand that in my toy example Singleton is not necessary, but making it necessary would over-complicate the example I think.

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/prologic/0c47f6ea744fd00c9087

Comment: Unfortunately multiprocessing is going to pickle the state of any globals in the parent process into the each child process; so I'm not sure you want to define "class attributes" like this.

Comment: Just doing some more testing on your *contrived* example and it does what you want it do; so I'm even more confused as to *what you're trying to do* now :)

Comment: Do you need this to work for ``processes=1`` or ``processes=10`` or any number of processes?

Comment: If I use N processes to run the function for M different arguments, N instances get created. I would like M instances created - one for each set of arguments. It would then work for any number of  processes.

Comment: If this is your requirement; you're going to have to use ``mutiproecssing.Process`` and manage a pool of workers yourself. ``multiprocessing.Pool`` is not designed for your particular use-case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78520/discussion-between-camz-and-james-mills).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay; paraphrasing:

> I want to create N processes to run the function for M different
>   arguments; but instead of N worker processes I want M worker
>   processes; one per permutation of arguments.

This really isn't possible with [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) as it wasn't designed for this use-case. It's more analogous to the builtin [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function where you apply a function to a sequence of inputs that are CPU-bound across multiple worker processes.

You *will have to* manage a set of worker processes yourself using [`multiprocessing.Process()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With processes=1 I had thought it would create all 10 processes but only run 1 at once. But it seems it creates 1 and uses it 10 times.

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks for helping me understand your problem!